# iOS 9 Multitasking feature enable but restrict iPhone app to support only Portrait mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, multitasking

I have added support for multitasking feature in iOS 9. For that I have checked all orientations support in info.plist. My App is universal. For iPhone it only gives portrait mode support, but in that i have given all orientation support to one screen. 
Now I always want to launch app in Portrait mode on iPhone. Its working in all iPhone models except iPhone 6+ , who is giving orientation support to springboard. Please help, I have tried all possible combination without any success.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In supported orientations in your info.plist make sure Potrait (bottom home button) is at item0.  This will always launch application in Potrait.